# Is it possible to add all of a vector's numbers using <functional> and <algorithm>?

Tags: c++

I have been looking at this problem for a day now but I cannot seem to find the answer. I need to use  and  to add all of the elements of a vector.

So far I found http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/plus/ Is it possible to instead of adding 2 vector add its elements together? I can't find anything else that even comes close to doing what I want to do.

By the way I am new to the language. I don't need the code but just a hint in the right direction.

Comment: [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Comment: But that is not part of <algorithm> or <functional> I found that awnser to.

Comment: aahh oke because it wasn't between these http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/.

Comment: If you would be so kind to explain us why it's so important that functions of the headers `<algorithm>` and `<functional>` are used we may be able to help you furthe

Comment: @ArthurP.R. He's been working on a homework assignment for the past few days that seems to have the constraint that you can only use `<functional>` and `<algorithm>`.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Thanks for this information. People luckily already answered his question.

Comment: @MikeOttink is the constraint that you can only use the `<functional>` and `<algorithm>` *headers,* or does it say algorithms *library?* The algorithms library is listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and includes `<algorithm>`, `<numeric>` and parts of `<memory>` and `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: It literally says "Use functions from <algorithm> and <functional>". I did find numeric also but it is not a function from algorithm right?

Comment: @MikeOttink <numeric> is part of the algorithms library, but is not part of the <algorithm> header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm to preform this operation is in the `<numeric>` header, not in the `<algorithm>` header. See [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data = {1, 2, 10};
    const auto result = std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you insist on using functional and `<algorithm>` you could use [std::for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) and [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data = {1, 2, 10};
    int result = 0;

    std::function<void(int)> sum = [&result](int value){result += value;};
    std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), sum);

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depending on what type You would like to return by accumulate function You should use either 0 for integer or 0.0 for double result value.